# Connecting to two different wifi networks from 2 different devices(internal and external)

Tags: networking, wireless, server, ftp

I'm using an old laptop with ubuntu 14.04, and I need to have two wi-fi networks. I have an internal wifi device and an external usb wifi adapter. One of them has to be connected to a Wi-Fi network in order to be connected to the internet while the other has to host a separate local network through which I want to setup a local FTP shared server with users.

I have been trying out a few stuff by myself like hostapd for hosting, and vsftpd for ftp server. However I haven't been successful in having them both run simultaneously on the same laptop with two separate wifi devices.

I'm a networking noob myself, but I'm open to trying out. Linking me to some concepts or resources which will help me achieve the required configuration would be helpful.

They are not atheros drivers. From what I read before atheros chipset wifi device allows easily for just one device to act as a host and client at the same time. The one's I have are both Realtek Semiconductor Corp devices. Also further suggestions on bridging these two networks would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.garron.me/en/bits/ubuntu-configure-wired-or-wireless-network-only-for-internal-use-internet.html

> Say you have two network interfaces configured on your Ubuntu Desktop,
>   and you want one of them to be used for Internet and the other only
>   for its own internal resources.
>
> We will do this using the graphical interface and this how-to works
>   for both Unity and Gnome Shell.
>
> Go to System Settings and then to Network Settings.
>
> [image]
>
> Then select the interface you want limited for internal use, which can
>   be a wired interface or a wireless one:
>
> [image]
>
> Select routes, and in the next screen, toggle on "use this connection
>   only for resources of its network"
>
> [image]
>
> Click OK and enter your password where prompted.

Comment: Sorry, but my laptop needs to host one local network with a ftp server, while be connected to another network to access the internet. Normally, I would proceed to start a hotspot and once connected, I would use vsftpd to start the server from a static IP. But when I start my wireless hotspot, it says that I won't be able to access the internet while doing that. Any way around that ?